# Animation works only sometimes when app starts (fade in)

Tags: android, animation

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
overridePendingTransition(R.animation.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
}
```

> I use this code in my first activity. I want my first activity to be always launched with my fade_in animation. Most of the times it works well when I use overridePendintTransition in onResume AND onCreate. I want it to work EVERYTIME. I tried every combination with onResume, onStart, onRestart, onCreate. I put overridePendintTransition in only one of them, I put overridePendintTransition in everyone of them, and so on. So the code I posted is the combination that works most of the times. Why does my main activity sometimes fade in when started and sometimes not: With same user´s input when leaving the app before starting it again i.e. backbutton, homebutton and so on?

Also: When the app is created for the first time after destroying the list of active apps it NEVER does the animation. Is there a way to fix this?

I´m dealing with this for days. Thank you very much!

Comment: did you try to put the `overridepending` before to call the `startActivity()` instead?

Comment: @Jerrol I don´t have startActivity() because this is in the first activity.